# How to solve this build gradle issue

Tags: java, android

I need help. i was trying to Update my;

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13' into new version that  will be accepted on more sites like firebase for using messaging so I'm recommended to updated to this version;
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'  but after Updating to that verision i got this issue please check this image to help me:

Comment: What issue? You forgot to add the issue that you have (the preferred way is to add the error message as text or alternatively attach a picture)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.